# several aggregation on laravel eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, database, eloquent

I have 4 model: Matter, Effect, Part, Property.
each Matter have several Part and each Part have several effects and properties.
each effect have several properties too.

I want this result with Laravel eloquent:

property_title | number of effects (effect_property) | number of effects (part_property) | effects of property

all of these values should be *in a limited matter ids* have given and *include properties that is in both any effects and any parts ( mean does not include properties that are only in parts of matters or which that are only on effects)* .

I made this query but take too long time on huge data:

```
 $result = Property::matterin($where)
            ->leftJoin('part_property', 'part_property.property_id', '=', 'properties.id')
            ->leftJoin('parts', 'parts.id', 'part_property.part_id')
            ->select(['parts.*','parts.matter_id','properties.id as id',  'properties.title as title',
                DB::raw('sum(if(part_property.part_id is not null,1,0 )) as count_partmatter'),
            ])
            ->whereNotNull(['properties.id'])
            ->groupBy(['properties.id'])
            ->get();

            foreach($result as $key => $prop) {
                if($prop->effects->isNotEmpty()){
                    $prop->effects()
                        ->leftJoin('effect_part','effect_part.effect_id','effects.id')
                        ->leftJoin('parts','parts.id','effect_part.part_id')
                        ->whereIn('parts.matter_id',$where);
                }else{
                    $result->forget($key);
                }
            }
```

but last column exists all effects of each property for all matters, not only that ones with specific $where matter ids.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to consider using the "withCount" function.
Abstract example

```
/** partProperty is any your relation*/
 $result = Property::withCount(['partProperty as count_partmatter' => function($q) {

      $q->select(DB::raw('sum(if(part_property.part_id is not null,1,0 )))
}])
```

Based on this example, build the rest of the chain in the same query.